# How to split a string in java by a non printable ascii character (Example - Record Seperator)

Tags: java, regex, split

In C# this would work - 
`String[] elements = sample.Split((char)30);`

What is the java equivalent?

Comment: what about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a regex string. For your purpose, you just need to convert the `char` to a `String`:

```
String[] elements = sample.split(Character.toString((char)30));
```

Comment: Or `sample.split("\u001E")`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand !!